# Error while reading CSV file using OleDBAdapter in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, oledb, read.csv

Need to read a csv file which contains more than 3 million records into a DataSet. Using OleDBAdapter to read the CSV file and move the entire content into a DataSet.

```
Dim FolderPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(FileDetails)
Dim tblCSV As New DataSet

Dim OleDBConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                                FolderPath & _
                                ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"";"

Dim OleDBConn As OleDbConnection

OleDBConn = New OleDbConnection(Trim(OleDBConnString))
OleDBConn.Open()

Dim OleDBAdapater As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" & Import_File_Name & "]", OleDBConn)

OleDBAdapater.Fill(tblCSV)

MessageBox.Show(tblCSV.Tables.Item(0).Rows.Count)
```

Comment: If only there was a way for us to know what the error message was.  I just can't think of any way that could happen.  Can you?

Comment: The error message is as follows:

'LCMG_ALL_MIGIE-INSTALLD-METERS-DETAILS-v1_20190619_20190619110209.csv' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.

Comment: If file name is modified then getting the following error:
Microsoft JET Database Engine
The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

Comment: You could try adding `Mode=Read` in the connection string, but that may not resolve the message. Are you receiving that message on the connection open method or a different call? What other app may have the file open? What directory path does the file reside in - are the NTFS permissions set to allow your app access to that folder/file?

Comment: The file is stored on "C:\Tools\SampleFiles".
The error occurs while executing the code "OleDBAdapater.Fill(tblCSV)"
Modified the code like below:
Dim SQLStatement As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & Import_File_Name & "]"
Dim OleDBAdapater As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLStatement, OleDBConn)

But it is of now use as the error persists.

Comment: Have you previously opened that file with a FileStream or something similar? Remove the brackets around the file name.

Comment: If you use an [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) to create the connection string *and* use the full path to the file, does it work any better?

Comment: Removed the bracket and used the OleDBConnectionStringBuilder but the error persists. The size of the file is around 200 MB. Is this 1 of the factor why file is failing to get opened as DataSet or DataTable?

Comment: Why do you open 3 million records at once? Do you display them?!? If not, I would read one line at a time instead and process them sequentially - that would dramatically improve the application's memory footprint...